# LINQ - How can I sort this data in one query

Tags: performance, linq, c#-4.0, lambda

I was wondering if there is any way to sort with LINQ this piece of data:

```
Firstname   lastname    age
Xxxxxxxxx   xxxxxxxxx   xxxx
Xxxxxxxxx   xxxxxxxxx   xxxx
* group YYYY <---- contained at firstName column
Xxxxxxxxx   xxxxxxxxx   xxxx
Xxxxxxxxx   xxxxxxxxx   xxxx
* group BBB
Xxxxxxxxx   xxxxxxxxx   xxxx
Xxxxxxxxx   xxxxxxxxx   xxxx
* group LLL
```

To:

```
Group       Firstname   lastname    age
YYYY        Xxxxxxxxx   xxxxxxxxx   xxxx
YYYY        xxxxxxxxx   xxxxxxxxx   xxxx 
BBB         Xxxxxxxxx   xxxxxxxxx   xxxx 
BBB         Xxxxxxxxx   xxxxxxxxx   xxxx
LLL         Xxxxxxxxx   xxxxxxxxx   xxxx
LLL         xxxxxxxxx   xxxxxxxxx   xxxx
```

I already did it, using a For statement, starting from the list’s end to get the group name then store that value in a local variable and keep filling the group column with that `“group name”` then I use LINQ to select all where the `FirstName` column not contain `*`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Show your current code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with an aggregate:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var data = new MyClass[]
    {
        new MyClass{FirstName="Tom"},
        new MyClass{FirstName="Dick"},
        new MyClass{FirstName="Harry"},
        new MyClass{FirstName="* group YYYY"},
        new MyClass{FirstName="Matthew"},
        new MyClass{FirstName="Mark"},
        new MyClass{FirstName="Luke"},
        new MyClass{FirstName="John"},
        new MyClass{FirstName="* group BBB"},
        new MyClass{FirstName="Moe"},
        new MyClass{FirstName="Larry"},
        new MyClass{FirstName="Curly"},
        new MyClass{FirstName="* group LLL"},
    };

    var groups = new Dictionary<string, List<MyClass>>();
    data.Aggregate(new List<MyClass>(), (a, b) =>
    {
        if (b.FirstName.StartsWith("* group "))
        {
            groups[b.FirstName.Substring(8)] = a;
            return new List<MyClass>();
        }
        a.Add(b);
        return a;
    });

    foreach (var group in groups.Keys)
        foreach (var record in groups[group])
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", group, record.FirstName);
}

public class MyClass
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
YYYY Tom
YYYY Dick
YYYY Harry
BBB Matthew
BBB Mark
BBB Luke
BBB John
LLL Moe
LLL Larry
LLL Curly
```

Comment: Whoa!! just amazing and powerful. Thank you sir.